# Why destructor of global static variable is not called?

Tags: c++, singleton, destructor

I have the following singletone implementation:

```
class B   
{
  public:
    static B *getInstance()
    {
        if ( !m_data )
          m_data = new(std::nothrow) B;
        return m_data;
    }

  private:
    static B *m_data;

  private:
    B() { std::cout << "B::B() " << B::m_data << std::endl; }
   ~B() { std::cout << "B::~B()" << std::endl; }
    B( const B & ) = delete;
    B &operator=( const B & ) = delete;
};


B *B::m_data = nullptr;
```

In main() I have:

```
B *pSingletone = B::getInstance();
```

I was surprised to see that destructor was never called after I killed my program. What am I missing? Do we need destructor at all in this case?
My questions are about destructor only, not how bad or good singletons are. I know I don't have to allocate it on the heap.

Edit to summarize: as several people pointed out, only static pointer is destructed on program termination, not the object it pointed to. To destruct the object, explicit "delete" is needed. After the program terminated, the allocated memory is of course returned to the system but without destructor call. Thanks everybody!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern?rq=1

Comment: How did you detect that the destructor of the *pointer* `m_data` wasn't called? I'm pretty sure it *was* called but had no effect...

Comment: Yes it's compiled. I think it's more or less usual singleton implementation (with allocation on the heap).

Comment: The destructor of `m_data` will be called, but it's just a dumb pointer that doesn't do anything. The question is how `*B::getInstance()` is stored.

Comment: If you do manual memory management you have to go all the way and `delete B::getInstance();`. Alternatively use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique` so you don't need to worry about these things.

Comment: Just a note on the general approach: singletons are a bad idea and they become worse over time [as concurrency increases and singletons don't mix with concurrency at all]. If you insist to create a `static` object, at least make the initialization thread-safe, i.e., move the object *into* the function and initialize it in the definition, e.g. `B* foo(){ static B* rc = new B(); return rc; }`.

Comment: The destructor of the pointer was called, but not the destructor of the thing it points to.

Comment: @amin It's said "Destructors (12.4) for initialized objects of static storage duration (declared at block scope or at namespace scope) are called as a result of returning from main and as a result of calling exit". But I killed my program - should not it be called and print the message?

Comment: The object of `class B` is not static, it is created dynamically on the heap. Only the pointer pointing to it is static.

Comment: TT_ note that in the question you cite in your top comment only the question uses that style of singleton. The overwhelmingly upvoted answer recommends that you NOT use that style of singleton. There are a number of reasons, not the least being the problem you've just run into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would the destructor get called ?  You're not deleting the object.  In other words, you have a memory leak.

You could fix this by including this in the end of `main()`:

```
delete pSingletone;
```

You would have to make `B::~B()` public, though.

Comment: I don't think so. The destructor is intentionally made private so that the singleton would not be deleted until the end of main.

Comment: Think what you want.  You have a problem, I gave a suggestion for how to fix it.

Comment: I don't have a problem :) I have a question.

Comment: @TT_ Yet, this answer (in addition to many of the comments) states what is wrong. Since you allocate with `new`, the destructor would get called upon calling `delete` on the pointer received from `new`. Since you don't call `delete` - destructor is never invoked. Why were you expecting something different?

Comment: @Algirdas Well, the question was what I'm missing, so this is exactly this :)

Comment: `delete pSingletone;` at end of main assumes that other singleton destructors don't call `B::getInstance()`.

Answer (score 4):

The destructor isn't being called because you're calling `new` without ever calling `delete` on `m_data`. I propose the following to avoid manual allocation, getting rid of `m_data`:

```
static B *getInstance(){
    static B theInstance; // initialized during first call, destroyed after main exits
    return &theInstance;
}
```

Comment: @SidS one can always use smart poiners to dynamic allocate it and still have all the benefits.

Comment: @SidS no, the instance lives in static program memory, not on the stack, since it will persist after getInstance() returns which is key

Comment: `GetInstance()` can even return reference instead of pointer.